# How to play a video in uiview Xcode obj C

Tags: ios

I Need to play a video when the view load but, other code i have try to do the video player comes up. I want to play the video in the UIVIEW. Can someone please help!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use an AVPlayer, specifying an AVPlayerItem.  This should allow you to use multiple AV items within a single view.

Basically, everything is explained here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html